# What might explain the [blastall] ERROR: Arguments must start with '-' error?

Tags: linux, bash, bioinformatics, blast

I am trying to pipe a QuerySequences using bash to perform a blastn on a ReferenceGenome. The problem is that I have to many sequences and to avoid producing a file with to many unnecesary registers (memory issues), I want to limit my output to those results with a percent of identity of 90% or higher.

I have run the following script without the flag I am going to mention afterwards and it works perfectly.

```
   #-perc_identity 80?????
   blastall -p blastn -d ReferenceGenome -i QuerySequences -G 1 -E 2 -W 15 -F "m D" -U -e 1e-20 -m 8 -a 8 -o NAME.blast.out
```

But, when I try with -perc_identity 90 flag I get the following error.

```
 [blastall] ERROR: Arguments must start with '-' (the offending argument #4 was: '90')
```

I have proved the flag in several position (after the blastn, after Querygenome, after "m D") and the only thing that changes is the number after the # in the Error.

Does anybody knows the probable reason of this error?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I don't know blast/blastall in the slightest but it sounds like `-perc_identity` doesn't expect an argument in the next position. Does it perhaps want to be `-perc_identity=##` or does it want to be specified some other way?

Comment: I don't know the command at all, but looking at [its man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/blast2.1.html), all options are short options; there's no such thing as `-perc_identity` at all. Maybe you are using something different?

Comment: @4ae1e1 That might work only for blast2 and megablast.

Comment: @EtanReisner No. I am sure it is that way. If you type blastn -help in the terminal you will see:               -perc_identity <Real, 0..100>

Comment: Given the look of that command line I'm assuming `blastall` is a wrapper around the other commands? If `blastn` claims to support it I'm going to guess that perhaps `blastall` was not properly updated to support that and is getting confused before passing it to `blastn` correctly.

Comment: @EtanReisner that might be an possibility. But I haven't found reports about the same error in the internet and because what I am doing is a pretty straightforward procedure in bioinformatics somebody else must have done it before. Therefore, I have sufficient reason to think the error is in my code and not in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use a Blast+ option with the legacy program blastall. Try installing blast+ and running the blastn program

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a parameter for minimum percent identity.  There are options to limit the output results to X number of hits.

Percent identity isn't even that useful because it doesn't take into account the length of the hit.  `e-value` which takes the identity AND the length into account to give you the probability that the alignment occurred by chance.

Usually, I think what people usually do is get the hits back and take the best X hits based on `e-value`.  Remember, the lower the `e-value` the better.

Comment: The parameter exists indeed and is supposed to be operative in all distribution. Look in Table C2 in this NCBI [www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK279675/]. If you type blastn -help, it also appears. I can't go into to much detail but, in my case, it is operative for what I am trying to do (is what I need, in fact). I can't get all the hits and then parse the results because of the memory issue mentioned. A preprove showed that more than 99% of the hits were below 90. Therefore, if I avoid saving those hits, my memory will suffix my temporary necessity.

Comment: I'm not sure why memory is such as issue. You don't have to store the raw results in a file or save it all in memory. You can stream through line by line and only keep the lines you care about